# A curious integer sequence

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, integers

We define $a(n)$ to be the $n$th term of the sequence defined by
$$
a(0)=a(1)=1 , a(2)=2 , a(n)=m,
$$
where $m$ is the largest number less than equal to $a(n-1)+a(n-2)$ so that $$
\gcd(m,a(k))=1 \text{ for all }1<k \leq n-1.
$$
Hence it's somewhat similar to Fibonacci sequence for first few values:
$$
a(2)=2 , a(3)=3 , a(4)=5.
$$
But now next term won't be $a(4)+a(3)=5+3=8$ as $a(2)=2|8$ hence we subtract $1$ and check whether it's co-prime to its previous terms or not. 
This becomes my sequence **A345020** in OEIS. 
Also for first $13$ values $a(n)$ is always prime , but the first composite number that appears is $a(14)=361$ and again followed by primes.
**Questions**
• What will be the asymptotic relation for the $n$th term?
• Are there infinitely many primes in the sequence?


**My approach**

1. In order to deduce some useful results I started with comparing it to the sequence of largest prime $\leq a(n-1)+a(n-2)$. 
   The variation started at $n=14$ where the prime was $359$ and the corresponding term in my sequence was $361$. And it's known for the sequence of largest prime $\leq a(n-1)+a(n-2)$ that :
   $$a(n)\sim c\cdot \phi ^n $$
   where $c=0.258616....$
   My approach was to take the arithmetic mean of Binet's formula for Fibonacci number and this asymptotic relation as it can be easily proved that our sequence lies in between. But how can I improve this weaker asymptotic relation obtained by taking the A.M . \
2. I haven't worked on it completely but using some little manipulations I was able to deduce that it's most likely to be true.
   (Note : I can be wrong with their infinitude , but it was just my reasoning).
   Any help is appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: @JohnOmielan You're right, the [sequence defined in OEIS](http://oeis.org/A345020) has $k \le n-1$ instead of $n$.

Comment: I apologize for the typo over there. I've edited it accordingly. Thank you for notifying.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us here which of the numbers among the entries at your OEIS sequence are not prime (and maybe even give their prime factors -- I'll venture to guess that every prime number will eventually appear as a divisor of one of the entries).

Comment: The numbers 44393 , 116227 , 188063 , 304289 , 492343 , 796627 , 2085593 , 37424333 , 60553837 are not primes in the entries. (Note I have just checked it till the last non-prime mentioned above.)